# Filter / Search function on Array of Structs, to display within tableView

Tags: swift, struct

I have created my own Struct object, that is populated from the Photos framework with each "moment" an image was contained in, and other metadata.

```
struct MomentImage {
    var momentNo : Int
    var index : Int
    var image : UIImage
}
```

I would like to populate a tableView, split with:

- Sections, which map to `momentNo`
- Cells, which map to `index`

In `tableView(cellForRowAt indexPath)`, I have printed out:

`print("location: \(indexPath.section) and \(indexPath.row)")`

But the Section value only ever prints "0". I expected my print statements to occur through all the sections in this table (with my test data, this is actually 13 sections)

How do I filter / retrieve this object at these 2 indices from my array of `var moments = [MomentImage]`...

Using `array.filter { }` seems the most obvious way. How do I pass in a 2nd property to check (i.e. momentNo AND index) within the same call?

`let filteredassets = assets.filter { $0.momentNo == indexPath.section }`

is my current code.

Note, the images need to be encodable, hence extracting from the PHImageManager into a distinct UIImage within a Struct that should itself be encodable.

Comment: You can try let filteredassets = assets.filter { $0.momentNo == indexPath.section && ... } ?

Comment: @Vicaren you were correct, hadn't even thought of this construct

Answer (score 1):

As provided by @Vicaren, applying a `&&` after the 1st parameter converts into to a 2-property IF AND statement

`$0` is still available to select, simply choose another available property to test.

My own example results in:

`let filteredassets = assets.filter { $0.momentNo == indexPath.section && $0.index == indexPath.row }`